# how to make kimlabs/gentelella theme side menu responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am working with my students on some academic project for university web application. We are using [kimlabs/gentelella](https://github.com/kimlabs/gentelella) theme for front end.

---

Everything is working well except side-menu responsive functionality.
We are unable to navigate all the menu items listed in side menu.

---

This issue was also reported at [github-issue](https://github.com/kimlabs/gentelella/issues/23) but no solutions are available there. Its demo also has the same issue. Demo available [here](http://demo.kimlabs.com/gentelella/production/index.html)

I appreciate your interest in solving this.

Comment: I already made a PR fix for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set position of sidebar from fixed to absolute in order to navigate all the menu items.

```
   body.nav-sm .container.body .left_col {
    width: 70px;
    padding: 0;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to edit script js/custom.js and comment out the slideUp-call from line 20.

```
//$('ul', this).slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the menu_fixed class added to the left_col. Just removed this class.

i.e. I changed
  `<div class="col-md-3 left_col menu_fixed">`

to 
   `<div class="col-md-3 left_col">`

This allowed the menu to scroll along with the rest of the page.